# 405 error - UnsupportedApiVersion : The requested resource with API version '1.0' does not support HTTP method 'POST'

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a feature in my application. Here I need to call a POST method, but I'm facing issue saying 'UnsupportedApiVersion 405 error'. Please find my code below. 
**site.html**

```
<!-- Is Synced with Data Factory? -->
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="isSynchronized">Is Synced with data factory:</label>
<div class="col-sm-7" id="isSynchronized">
   <input class="control-label" type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!shell.connectedUserPermissions['editdatafactorysync']" ng-click="vm.datafactoryIsSynchronized()" ng-model="vm.site.IsDFSynchronized" />
</div>
```

**site.controller.ts**

```
datafactoryIsSynchronized() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.siteService.datafactoryIsSynchronized(this.site.Id, this.site.IsDFSynchronized).then((response: any) => {
        this.site.IsDFSynchronized = response;
        this.modalService.notify(`Data factory activation exchange is successfully updated.`);
    }).catch((errorData) => {
        if (errorData) {
            this.modalService.error(`Something went wrong, Please try again.`);
        }
    }).finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
}
```

**site.service.ts**

```
private routes = {
    IsDFSynchronized: '/site/{:siteId}/{:isDFSynchronized}',
};

datafactoryIsSynchronized(siteId: number, isSyncValue: boolean): ng.IPromise<boolean> {
    const url = this.routes.IsDFSynchronized.replace('{:siteId}', siteId.toString()).replace('{:isDFSynchronized}', isSyncValue.toString());
    return this.restService.post(url, null).then((response: any) => {
        console.log('THE RESPONSE IS', response.data);
        return response.data;
    }).catch((response: any) => {
        return this.$q.reject(response);
    });
}
```

**SiteController.cs**

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[Route("site/{siteId}/{isDFSynchronized}")]
public bool UpdateDataFactorySync([FromUri] int siteId, [FromUri] bool isSynchronized)
{
    var connectedUser = this.permissionService.GetConnectedUser();

    this.permissionService.CheckUserPermission(connectedUser, PermissionConstant.EditDataFactorySync);

    bool result = this.siteService.UpdateDataFactorySync(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, siteId, isSynchronized);
    if (result)
    {
        this.applicationDataAccess.LogAction(connectedUser.CurrentEnvironment, connectedUser.Email, LogActionConstants.Action.EditDataFactorySync, string.Format(LogActionConstants.Message.EditDataFactorySync, siteId, isSynchronized));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**DataAccess.cs**

```
public bool UpdateDataFactorySync(string envCode, int siteId, bool isSynchronized)
{
    envCode.ThrowIfNull();

    string url = $"sites/{siteId}/syncWithDataFactory/{isSynchronized}";
    var result = this.ExecuteAndParseWebRequestForEnv<HttpResponseMessage>(envCode, url, HttpMethod.Post);
    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent || result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In Insomnia/Postman, I am able to get 204 response.
The api endpoint : /api/v1/sites/{id}/syncWithDataFactory/{activate}

Please help me to fix this error. Thanks in advance.